# Sencha Touch 2 MultiSelect & ItemSelector

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Do Sencha Touch 2 has any alternatives like this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mode: 'MULTI'` in Ext.dataview.List http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-mode

Here is fiddle http://www.senchafiddle.com/#d6M07